# convert rows of dataframe to separate dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i need to convert to rows of a dataframe from separate 1 row dataframes. Looking for the most efficient / clean approach here.

I need to persist the column names, it is for a machine learning model and i basically need a list of dataframes.

My current solution:

```
def get_data(filename):
  dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
  dataframes = []
  for i,row in dataframe.iterrows():
      dataframes.append(row.to_frame().T)
  return dataframes
```

This looks very inefficient, maybe there is a cleaner shorter solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
dataframes = [dataframe.iloc[[i]] for i in range(len(dataframe))]
```

Or:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
dataframes = [x.to_frame().T for i,x in dataframe.T.items()]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect, the first method is faster than the second?

Comment: @stackofacc - Yop, unfortuantely generate many dataframes is slow...

Comment: what a pitty because i have to declare the dataframe as a variable then while for the slow method i could just do return [x.to_frame().T for i,x in pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';').T.items()]

Comment: This was not what i meant, the slow solution can be written as a one liner, the first one cannot. Or am i wrong?

Comment: @stackofacc - yop, you are right, but one line solution not mean the fastest ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_list = []
_ = dataframe.apply(lambda x: df_list.append(x.to_frame().T),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want is somethink like this:

```
start = 0
end = dataframe.shape[0]
dataframes = dataframe.loc[start:end]
```